# Searching for text within a particular 'Outlook Notes' note

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2013

Some of my Outlook notes hold quite a bit of useful information, and running upto about 50-60 odd lines of text. These are things that could alternatively have been bookmarks, but more truly are aids to memory. I classify my notes, s.t. each note holds information of similar kind.

However, my trouble is that I need to search text within those 50-60 lines, to pick the info I am looking for, but to the best of my knowledge, there is no function to search for text, within a particular note. Or is there ?

Comment: Which notes are you talking about? Notes attached to contacts?

Comment: Talking about Notes, which occur at top-level along with Calendar, Contacts, Tasks etc.

Comment: have you managed to find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find any elegant solution to this from within Outlook itself. Finally what I did (before we moved to Office 360, which seems to have removed Notes in Outlook in favour of OneNote) was to copy-paste the entire note in textpad and search it, every time/each time I've had to look for specific text.